# frameticks showing all ticks but favorite numbers

Tags: plotting

i have this plot with FrameTicks

```
 LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[x], {T, 0.1, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.05, 80}, {0, 7}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{2, 4, 6}, None}, {{0.1, 1, 10, 50}, None}}]
```

i get this figure.

[image]

but i want to get the second figure, with all ticks but favorite numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you override the `Automatic` setting you need to specify all of the ticks that you want.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

majorTick := {#1, #1, {0.0125`, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
           AbsoluteThickness[0.5]}} & ; 

minorTick = {#1, "", {0.0075`, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
         AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}} &;

minorXticks = minorTick /@ Flatten[Table[m*10^n, {n, -2, 1}, {m, 2, 10}]];
```

Your code indicates a [`LogLinearPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLinearPlot.html); however, the image is a [`LogLogPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html). Since your [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) corresponds to a `LogLinearPlot`

```
LogLinearPlot[T, {T, 0.1, 50}, PlotRange -> {{0.05, 80}, {0, 7}},
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {
   {Join[minorTick /@ Range[0, 7, 0.2], majorTick /@ Range[2, 7]], 
    Automatic},
   {Join[minorXticks, majorTick /@ {0.1, 1, 10}],
    Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Or if you want the second plot with the labels of the first

```
LogLinearPlot[T, {T, 0.1, 50}, PlotRange -> {{0.05, 80}, {0, 7}},
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {
   {Join[minorTick /@ Range[0, 7, 0.2], majorTick /@ Range[2, 6, 2]], 
    Automatic},
   {Join[minorXticks, majorTick /@ {0.1, 1, 10, 50}],
    Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your response. it really helped.
Actually I did not want LogLogPlot, so I used  Evaluate,

Comment: Thanks again for the edition